# How do I run a global npm program when an ubuntu program has the same name?

Tags: apt, 18.04, nodejs, npm

I installed `npm-check-updates` using `sudo npm install -g npm-check-updates`.

To use it I need to run `ncu` in the folder I want to check with it.

However, it appears there is a weather program in Ubuntu 18.04 that runs when you type `ncu` in the terminal. I want to run the node/npm command `ncu` and *not* the ncu weather program.

note: `type -a ncu` results in `ncu is /usr/local/bin/ncu`. This is the binary that runs when I try to run the globally install npm executable with `ncu`.

Comment: Can you update your question with results of `type -a ncu`?

Comment: Just add a script that runs the npm object using a different name that doesn't collide.  If the answer should be easier, it probably is...

Comment: I don't know how to run the npm object directly. Running `node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm-check-updates/ncu/index.js` does not work, for example.

Comment: @BillD The reason for my first question was to find out the names. What does `type -a ncu` display in the terminal? (Open terminal wtth `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`) After updating your question let me know by putting @WinEunuuchs2Unix into the comment. Thanks,

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I did do this, see above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the weather program `ncu` which is causing the conflict, the easiest solution would be to uninstall it using:

```
npm uninstall -g ncu
```

Comment: This is the opposite of the question I asked. I want to **keep and run** the npm program. The weather program is a regular binary in `/usr/local/bin` I could delete or rename this binary, but I am looking for a solution to specify the npm package.

Comment: There is an extensive conversation of your problem: https://github.com/ncu-weather/ncu-weather-cli/issues/2

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot that I accidentally installed `npm install -g ncu`, and this is what was causing the conflict. I thought it was some other binary included with Ubuntu. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Add to `~/.basrc`:

```
alias ncu="/path/to/desired/ncu"
```

Then,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Or, log out and log in

Comment: This doesn't work to run an npm-installed executable module. The ncu I want to run is not a normal binary.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on ubuntu 18.0.4.2 LTS Desktop.

So I first deleted ncu from my system thus deleting both weather and npm-dependency-updater with the command from **`npm uninstall -g ncu`.**

Then reinstalled npm-check-updates globally **`npm i -g npm-check-upates`** and bob's your uncle.

Installing npm-check-updates => auto-installs ncu "dependency-updater".

Thanks to the others for their shares.